# session variable or extra context?

Tags: django, django-sessions, django-context

I need to have a few variables accessible on almost every view.  I think I can see how to do it either using a context processor and "extra context" values, or by using session variables.  Are there advantages and disadvantages?  Which approach should I use?  Are there meaningful differences?  I see that to access session variables in a template, I have to enable django.core.context_processors.request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions is a good way to store variables for that you can use on other pages in your website. Nothing wrong with using sessions.